# Wait for an async methods to finish in a for loop

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

I have a for loop containing three asynchronous methods, and I want to make some treatment after this 3 async methods are finished.

```
 -(void)getAllUsersInformations{
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
           for(User *user in users){
              [self getUserInfo:user];
           }
      //Here, I want to reload the table view for example, after finishing the for loop (executing the whole three methods).
    });
}

-(void)getUserInfo:(User*)user{
     [self getInformations:user];
     [self getExperiences:user];
     [self getEducation:user];
}
```

Do you have any technic to have this result?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Are `getInformations`, `getExperiences` and `getEducation`, themselves, asynchronous methods? Or are they all synchronous methods that you'd dispatching asynchronously to some background queue? (Your edit to the question radically changes the answer.)

Comment: @Rob ; Yes, they're asynchronous! `getAllUsersInformations` `getInformations` `getExperiences` and `getEducation` are asynchronous.

Comment: @androniennn can you make the three `-getXXX` methods synchronous?

Comment: @AaronA. No, that's not possible, they have to be async .

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One GCD approach is to use `dispatch_group`. So, before you start an asynchronous task, call `dispatch_group_enter`, and then when the asynchronous task finishes, call `dispatch_group_leave`, and you can then create a `dispatch_group_notify` which will be called when the asynchronous tasks finish. You can marry this with a completion block pattern (which is a good idea for asynchronous methods, anyway):

1. If `getInformations`, `getExperiences` and `getEducation` are, themselves, all asynchronous methods, the first thing you need is some mechanism to know when they're done. A common solution is to implement a completion block pattern for each. For example:

   ```
   // added completionHandler parameter which will be called when the retrieval
   // of the "informations" is done.

   - (void)getInformations:(User*)user completionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler {
       // do whatever you were before, but in the asynchronous task's completion block, call this
       // completionHandler()
       //
       // for example

       NSURLRequest *request;

       [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:nil completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
           // handle the request here

           // the important thing is that the completion handler should
           // be called _inside_ the this block

           if (completionHandler) {
               completionHandler();
           }
       }];
   }
   ```

   Repeat this process for `getExperiences` and `getEducation`, too.
2. Then, you can use a dispatch group to notify you of when each of these three requests are done done, calling a completion block in `getUserInfo` when that takes place:

   ```
   // added completion handler that will be called only when `getInformations`,
   // `getExperiences` and `getEducation` are all done.
   //
   // this takes advantage of the completion block we added to those three
   // methods above

   - (void)getUserInfo:(User*)user completionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler {
       dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

       // start the three requests

       dispatch_group_enter(group);
       [self getInformations:user completionHandler:^{
           dispatch_group_leave(group);
       }];

       dispatch_group_enter(group);
       [self getExperiences:user completionHandler:^{
           dispatch_group_leave(group);
       }];

       dispatch_group_enter(group);
       [self getEducation:user completionHandler:^{
           dispatch_group_leave(group);
       }];

       // this block will be called asynchronously only when the above three are done

       dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
           if (completionHandler) {
               completionHandler();
           }
       });
   }
   ```
3. And you then repeat this process at the `getAllUsersInformations`:

   ```
   // call new getUserInfo, using dispatch group to keep track of whether
   // all the requests are done

   -(void)getAllUsersInformations {

       dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

       for(User *user in users){
           dispatch_group_enter(group);

           [self getUserInfo:user completionHandler:^{
               dispatch_group_leave(group);
           }];
       }

       dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
           [self.tableView reloadData];
       });
   }
   ```

---

Two final thoughts:

1. Having outlined all of that, I must confess that I would probably wrap these requests in concurrent/asynchronous custom `NSOperation` subclasses instead of using dispatch groups. See the "Configuring Operations for Concurrent Execution" section of the [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationObjects/OperationObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH101-SW8). This is a more radical refactoring of the code, so I won't tackle that here, but it lets you constrain the number of these requests that will run concurrently, mitigating potential timeout issues.
2. I don't know how many of these user requests are going on, but you might want to consider updating the UI as user information comes in, rather than waiting for everything to finish. This is, again, a more radical refactoring of the code, but might lead to something that feels more responsive.

Comment: What an explanation! Understood the technic, and I'll try to implement it. I'll leave a feedback ;).

Comment: the last `group_notify` that reloads the tableview is never called. I don't know why especially as the `group_leave` of `getUserInfo` is called.

Comment: First, make sure that the final group notify wasn't called (and that it's not just a problem that the table reload didn't work properly). Second, to diagnose this, log the group enter's and leave's in `getAllUsersInformations` and make sure they _all_ got called.

Comment: Thank you very much Rob, it's working just like I wanted. Thank you too for the final thoughts, the 2)- I already have this in mind, and for the first one I have to read the doc and perhaps change into it like you advised. Thanks :) ...

Answer (score 0):

Try to do a block with completion, you can't do this with a for loop if the methods are async. you have to call getUserInfo one by one after the completion of the previous. I think this gonna be solved your problem.

```
  -(void)getAllUsersInformations{
    [self registerUserAtIndex:0];
  }

  - (void) registerUserAtIndex: (NSInteger ) userIndex
  {
  RegisterOperation *op = [[RegisterOperation alloc] initWithUser:[users objectAtIndex:userIndex]];
  [RegisterOperation setResultCompletionBlock:^(BOOL *finished, NSInteger userIndex) {
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      if (userIndex++ < [users count] {
         [self registerUserAtIndex:userIndex++];
      } else {
         [myTableView reloadData];
      }
   }];
  [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperation:op];
 }
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Rop Answer with **swift**:

```
func processData()
{
    let group: dispatch_group_t  = dispatch_group_create()

    for item in data as! Object {
        dispatch_group_enter(group)
        item.process(completion: {() -> (Void) in
          dispatch_group_leave(group)
        })
      }

    dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        //Do whatever you want
      })
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    // Background work
       for(User *user in users){
          [self getUserInfo:user];
       }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     //reload tableview , this is on main thread.
    });
});
```

Comment: The three methods in `-getUserInfo:` are asynchronous, won't that cause this to return early?

Comment: @AaronA. : Exactly Aaron.

Comment: No, those methods will be called synchronously on background. Indeed if you'll put a breakpoint on entering the block it will pass over it. When the for loop will be finished the block `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     //reload tableview , this is on main thread.
    });` will be called on main thread. Do a quick test it should work.

Comment: @AdiPop, the three methods are Asynchronous, in a dispatch_async block. The reloading of the tableview will be executed before finishing executing the 3 methods.