# iOS: For-loop with methods that run in the background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, for-loop, objective-c-blocks

I have an array of id's in which I run a for loop on, and call a method that runs in the background (makes a network call to fetch data). How can I know when the for loop has finished and all the calls have finished as well?

At the moment the for loop is finishing before all the calls do which is expected. Should I use a while loop?

### Update (Finally got it working!)

I've posted my code here in the hope that it will help others. :)

Details: Following Andrey's advice, the first thing I did was to subclass `NSOperation` and do the following:

```
@interface AsyncOperation ()

@property (atomic, assign) BOOL _executing;
@property (atomic, assign) BOOL _finished;

@end

@implementation AsyncOperation

- (void)start {

    if ([self isCancelled]) {

        //Move the operation to the finished state if it is canceled.
        [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
        self._finished = YES;
        [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
        return;
    }

    //If the operation is not canceled, begin executing the task.
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(main) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
    self._executing = YES;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];

}

- (void)main {
    if ([self isCancelled]) {
        return;
    }
}

- (BOOL)isAsynchronous {
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)isExecuting {
    return self._executing;
}

- (BOOL)isFinished {
    return self._finished;
}

//Make sure to expose this method in the header file
- (void)completeOperation {

    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];

    self._executing = NO;
    self._finished = YES;

    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
}
```

Finally, in my method I did:

```
    //Setup NSOperation Queue
    self.queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    self.queue.name = @"myQueue";

    //Set Queue Observer (Using Third Party Library KVOController)
    [self.KVOController observe:self.queue keyPath:@"operationCount" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld|NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew block:^(id observer, NSOperationQueue *queue, NSDictionary *change) {

        //Check if all operations concluded
        if (queue.operationCount == 0) {

            //Remove Observer
            [self.KVOController unobserve:self.queue];

            //DO SOMETHING NOW THAT EVERYTHING IS DONE
        }
    }];

    //Loop through my chats and fetch each one
    for (NSString *chatId in chatIds) {

        //Observe Operation
        AsyncOperation *operation = [[AsyncOperation alloc] init];
        [self.KVOController observe:operation keyPath:@"isExecuting" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew block:^(id observer, EMKAsyncOperation *myOperation, NSDictionary *change) {

            //Check if operation is executing
            if ([myOperation isExecuting]) {

                //Fetch Chat (My async method)
                [self fetchChatWithId:chatId inBackgroundWithBlock:^(Chat *chat, BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {

                    //Check for error
                    if (!error) {

                        //DO WHATEVER I DO AFTER FETCHING COMPLETED

                        //Complete operation manually 
                        [myOperation completeOperation];

                        //Remove Observer
                        [self.KVOController unobserve:myOperation];

                    } else {

                       //Error Cancel Everything
                       finalError = error;

                       NSLog(@"Error fetching all chats: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

                       //Cancel Operations
                       [self.queue cancelAllOperations];

                        //Complete operation
                        [myOperation completeOperation];

                        //Remove Observer
                        [self.KVOController unobserve:myOperation];
                    } 
                }];
            }
        }];

        //Add Operation
        [self.queue addOperation:operation];
    }
```

Hope this helps people!

Comment: you can make condition like i == array.count-1 in side forloop so you know that loop is finished or for block you may check the link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26343351/wait-for-an-async-methods-to-finish-in-a-for-loop

Comment: Either use `NSOperation` or `recursive` method instead of loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like the problem is not in finding out when the loop is finished, which is obvious but rather when all the network calls are finished. 
So this is what I would do. I would wrap each network call into an instance of `NSOperation` class and add each operation into a `NSOperationQueue`. This class has `operationsCount` property which is key value observable. So using KVO you can observe changes in this property. Once `operationsCount` is equal to 0 - you're done. All the requests have finished

Comment: Nice! To be honest I've never used NSOperationQueue. If you could point me in the right direction, that would be really useful!

Comment: this is a very good and clear tutorial on that topic http://web.archive.org/web/20150417045614/http://www.raywenderlich.com/19788/how-to-use-nsoperations-and-nsoperationqueues

Comment: Thanks Andrey! I'm not done implementing it to check if it works, but I do have one question. Once a block has completed, I add the returned object to a mutable array (all blocks return a unique object). Do I need to use a mutex lock for an array which just adds objects?

Comment: Cool thank you! Last question. Where would I check the operationsCount?

Comment: you need to familiarize yourself with the concept of KVO: http://www.appcoda.com/understanding-key-value-observing-coding/
this will answer your question.

Comment: You're amazing! Okay I've tested it and it's almost there. I forgot to mention that my method which fetches data is asynchronous. This means the operation is being "completed" even before my method's success / failure block is called. I updated my answer with my code. How can I make the queue wait until the block is returned before declaring it finished?

Comment: Instead of adding operation with block you need to subclass NSOperation class with  your implementation. An operation queue keeps an operation inside until the operation is cancelled or finished. Therefore in your subclass operation implementation you need to set property isFinished to YES in the completion block. You will also need to call methods willChangeValueForKey and didChangeValueForKey right before and right after self.isFinished = YES. This should do the trick.

Comment: Another option could be a semaphore which would make the code inside your block wait until the completion block is called

Comment: Brilliant! I went the subclassing route and it's working beautifully. I've posted my code in my answer to help future developers. Let me know if you see any mistakes as I'm new to all this. Thank you so much for helping me learn about it all! You sir deserve an award :)

Answer (score 2):

Create an integer variable and increment it whenever the completion block is invoked. This way, you will have a track of how many responses have you got. If that count == array.count, all the responses have been received.